# Simple set theory question with empty elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Very simple question, I prob look like an idiot lol. but hey, I'm here to learn

so if I have a set A where
A = {$a∈ℕ$ | $a^2 = 5$}

is set A then A = ∅ or is it A = {∅}?

also, if it's the latter, if I have set B say B = {1, 2, 3} and want to find the union of A and B, is it {1, 2, 3} or {∅, 1, 2, 3}?
and what about the intersection? if A = {∅, 1, 2} and B = {1, 2, 3}, then A n B = {1, 2} right?

Comment: Elements aren't empty.  Sets are.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $x$ is any element of $\{\,a\in\Bbb N\mid a^2=5\,\}$, then both $x\in \Bbb N$ and $x^2=5$. Soooo, is either of these conditions true when $x=\emptyset$?

Comment: oh so it's the previous.. thanks :)

Comment: You’ve activated my trap card (which is that natural numbers can be represented as Von Neumann ordinals, so in this representation it’s accurate to say $\emptyset \in \mathbb{N}$, but also that this is totally irrelevant to the OP).

Answer (score 0):

This got a bit long so I will write it here. One way of seeing the notation of sets  is what is "in" the curly bracket and the empty set can also be written as $\{\}$ which is notation that is seen. The empty set while not containing anything is itself a thing the same way and empty box is a thing. The set $\{\emptyset\}$ is not the empty set the same way a box containing an empty box is not empty.
Second notice $A$ must contain natural numbers or rather it is a subset of the natural numbers on the $\{\emptyset\}=\{\{\}\}$ is a set containing the empty set. Unless you are working with a particular construction of natural numbers done in axiomatic set theory the empty set is not a natural number so the set $\{\emptyset\}$ cannot be $A$ simply because it contains an non natural number element